# В woocommerce (wordpress) НЕ отображается картинка товара

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В woocommerce (wordpress) НЕ отображается картинка товара ни в админке, ни на странице магазина, ни на странице товара...
Пробовал на нескольких темах, результат тот же! В записях картинки отображаются...
Подскажите в чем может быть причина? Только начал пробовать работать с woocommerce...

Comment: См  html-код и проверяй физ. наличие/доступность.

Comment: @SeVlad , проверил код, нашел изображение, оно есть в наличии, права 777 (да, это не правильно, но это тестовый (учебный проект). А иконки изображений так и не отображаются....в чем может быть  еще причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно больше инфы. 
Если посмотреть в файлы плагина которые генерят магазин \wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\ для магазина используется content-product.php в нем выводит картинку

```
/**
     * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
```

т.е. у нас в этом месте выполняются 2 хука woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flas и woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail нас интересует второй, находим его по файлам плагина:

```
    if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail' ) ) {

        /**
         * Get the product thumbnail for the loop.
         *
         * @subpackage  Loop
         */
        function woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail() {
            echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
        }
    }
```

=>

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail' ) ) {
        /**
         * Get the product thumbnail, or the placeholder if not set.
         *
         * @subpackage  Loop
         * @param string $size (default: 'shop_catalog')
         * @param int $deprecated1 Deprecated since WooCommerce 2.0 (default: 0)
         * @param int $deprecated2 Deprecated since WooCommerce 2.0 (default: 0)
         * @return string
         */
        function woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail( $size = 'shop_catalog', $deprecated1 = 0, $deprecated2 = 0 ) {
            global $post;
            $image_size = apply_filters( 'single_product_archive_thumbnail_size', $size );

            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                $props = wc_get_product_attachment_props( get_post_thumbnail_id(), $post );
                return get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, $image_size, array(
                    'title'  => $props['title'],
                    'alt'    => $props['alt'],
                ) );
            } elseif ( wc_placeholder_img_src() ) {
                return wc_placeholder_img( $image_size );
            }
        }
    }
```

Условие показывает, что функцию можно переписать в теме (Для этого просто скопируйте ее в functions.php).
Выведите get_the_post_thumbnail_url() в начале - выведет ли что либо, какое-то "echo '!!!';" в условии проверки наличия картинки - есть ли у данных товаров вообще картинка.

Answer (score 0):

Autoprimize плагин, поставил галку на "добавить try-catch обертывание?" и все ок.

Comment: Извините, вы считаете, что уже принятый ТС ответ требует дополнения?